# How can I improve the team efficiency

Tags: team-management, time-management, task-management, strategy, project-leader

I am 20 years old and together with my friend have been working on side projects since 4 years ago. This summer we finished high school and thought of taking things more seriously.

We took a worker to help us manage the webpages, or better say an assistant.
It is not that we are lazy but we want to focus on other things too.

For the moment we have 2 websites where we advertise businesses: a 1e-commerce website and a Hostel.

We want to put things to work and secure a monthly payment so we can continue to our next ideas. (of which we have plenty)

Next week we are hiring another worker to speed up the work and to add some pressure on us.

What help could you give me on organizing or managing?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Could you specify your problem more concretely?

Comment: Sergey thanks for taking your time. The problem is I don't know it either. I want some tips or tools   so I never lose focus. If I may ask What work do you do maybe this will help me ask sth specifically

Comment: This isn't so much an answer but a direction to look in. Take a look at Kanban. It won't solve problems, but it will help make the way you work more visible so you can see where things are going well and where you need to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really broad question so it's hard to make a canonical answer, but one thing did stick out to me. It's mildly concerning that you're hiring so early. Have you already calculated hat you can afford to pay this new employee with your current growth, without going bankrupt? See [Default Alive or Default Dead?](http://www.paulgraham.com/aord.html) for more details.

Comment: If things go as planned the first worker will provide enough money to pay for himslef and another one, the 2 worker will do the same until we have 10 and than make another plan. I belive We need some preasure to keep on moving + In albania the worker cost 100 euro. + now that I am under preasure I have been asking on online communities and I must say I have learned today from online than I have the previos month

Comment: May I also know what job you do so I may ask you more specific....... it is the first time for me asking online and find it very usefull. I thank you for your time and meanwhile wonder why you took your time answering     thank you again

Comment: Thank you for the info you provided, people like you give me the courage to go further

Comment: @Glendi `If things go as planned the first worker will provide enough money to pay for himself` isn't a business plan. If your developer knows how to make money to cover his own expenses, why would he do that for you instead of himself? The _company_ needs to make enough money to cover his costs, and then let him bring money in if he can. I'm impressed at where you are at 20, but I'd find a entrepreneur mentor who can help you avoid mistakes they made. I wouldn't hire until I had a solid understanding of money and how it works. I'd instead focus on increasing my output per hour myself.

Comment: The reason people wonr work for themself is easy. They cant manage theirself. For example 3 years ago me and my friend did a website with WordPress and in the following week we went to all the businesses located in the beach and advertised them for 30 euro than we quit. This year I saw the page and it was ranked 6 on google soo we decided to develop it more the worker is putting all the business in the web for free + he is not doing anything I havent done myself + I hold all the card in my hand + he has the same payments as others and work 3 hours less